# maven test deployment failure

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm just getting started with using Maven as build system.

Using:
Java 1.6
Apache Maven 3.0.3
JBoss 7.1.1-final
Eclipse Juno (although this is likely irrelevant since I see the same failures on the command line)

I created a new mvn project using the archetype: jboss-javaee6-webapp-ear-blank-archetype

I then added some changes to get things working with Arquillian per the [Arquillian Getting Started Guide][1]

I'm trying to write my first test of a Stateless Session Bean. Really the test does nothing yet, indeed the test code isn't even running.

The issue is occurring between the mvn goals 'process-test-classes' and 'test'. Basically it seems the test.war that maven generates and attempts to deploy is not resolving all the classes correctly, despite the fact that everything compiles fine.

Since I've given control to Maven I don't really know why Maven is unhappy or how to fix it.

Any ideas of what is causing the issues or how I can begin to diagnose the situation?  (the -X option gives lots of configuration details, but no direction of where to hunt)

For completeness here is the server and test output:

```
12:33:06,096 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/standalone/deployments
12:33:06,107 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
12:33:06,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
12:33:06,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:33:06,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 3054ms - Started 138 of 214 services (74 services are passive or on-demand)dd/mc
12:33:11,052 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014900: Content added at location /usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/standalone/data/content/e5/ae1c4f030493900cf7d3fb8d2ea98813c04966/content
12:33:11,065 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "test.war"
12:33:11,485 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class dd.mc.database.access.SiteAccess in Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link dd/mc/database/access/SiteAccess (Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dd/mc/database/access/SiteAccessLocal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dd.mc.database.access.SiteAccessLocal from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 26 more

12:33:11,507 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class dd.mc.database.access.SiteAccess in Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link dd/mc/database/access/SiteAccess (Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:225)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dd/mc/database/access/SiteAccessLocal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dd.mc.database.access.SiteAccessLocal from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 22 more

12:33:11,528 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "test.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Could not load EJB class dd.mc.database.access.SiteAccess
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:227)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dd.mc.database.access.SiteAccess from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:225)
    ... 7 more

12:33:11,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "test.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"test.war\""}}
12:33:11,542 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "test.war"

12:33:11,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war in 31ms
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.211 sec (WeldClassImpl.java:154) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:118) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:49) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:40) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:149) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dd.mc.database.User from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:95) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
    ... 29 more

12:33:13,384 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /test
12:33:13,461 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 4) JBAS018559: Deployed "test.war"
12:33:14,101 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment test.war
12:33:14,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war in 62ms
12:33:14,161 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014901: Content removed from location /usr/local/jboss-7.1.1-final/standalone/data/content/00/85445003ed8a1c42f91054bf5010444853af82/content
12:33:14,162 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018558: Undeployed "test.war"
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.543 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that you have missed adding relevant class files or jars in to the test artifact. Check whether all artifacts are added.